# How can I stop the button collector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The problem is that I need to handle button presses so that if I press a new button, the collector of the previous button stops, so that there are no errors with unknown interactions or the interaction has already been confirmed:

```
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
 at handleErrors (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.update (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:233:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\buttons\moderates\listRaiting.js:51:7) {
  requestBody: { files: [], json: { type: 7, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1108982827606888478/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwODk4MjgyNzYwNjg4ODQ3ODpWYW0wbnVoR2hpdDJxeHlhYjlzZ1FvaVZEVXJaQUhzaTNHWTF4Sm1rVW5FbnVTYjE0NjdETGZrUndZV1A2T3ExY0RYdWhYcEgwR2JOWHdIcXV4czJBTEF3aUkyQ281QnlhR3RsZUdIcktkRGRjV3hjNEY1OTdzS0tyUG5hU0doYw/callback'
```

My code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
} = require('discord.js');

const muteButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/muteButton.js');
const unMuteButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/unMuteButton.js');
const warnButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/warnButton.js');
const unWarnButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/unWarnButton.js');
const listRaitingButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/listRaiting.js');
const infractionButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/infractionButton.js');
const raitingButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/raitingButton.js');
const unRaitingButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/unraitingButton.js');
const unraitingButton = require('../../buttons/moderates/unraitingButton.js');

const collectors = {};

async function createCollector(interaction, customId, executeFunction) {
  const filter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.isButton() && i.customId === customId;

  const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });

  collector.on('collect', async i => {
    executeFunction(i);
  });

  collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collector для кнопки ${customId} завершен. Собрано ${collected.size} элементов.`);
  });
}    
  
  module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName('moderate')
      .setDescription('Предоставляет модераторскую панель с действиями, такими как мут, размут, предупреждение и т.д.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
      const member = interaction.member;
      const moderatorRole = member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Модератор');
      if (!moderatorRole) {
          return interaction.reply({ content: 'Вы не являетесь Модератором, у вас нет прав для использования этой команды.', ephemeral: true });
      }
  
      for (let collector in collectors) {
          collectors[collector].stop();
      }
  
      const filter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
      const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });
    
      const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('mute')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('unmute')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('warn')
            .setEmoji('⚠️')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('unwarn')
            .setEmoji('❌')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );
  
      const row1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
          new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('raiting')
            .setEmoji('✅')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('unraiting')
            .setEmoji('❎')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
              .setCustomId('listraiting')
              .setEmoji('')
              .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
              .setCustomId('infractions')
              .setEmoji('')
              .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
          );
    
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor(0x000000)
          .setTitle('Модераторская панель')
          .setDescription(`**Действия для управления порядком на сервере.**\n\n**1-ая строка кнопок:**\n\n — Выдать таймаут участнику\n — Снять таймаут с участника\n⚠️ — Выдать предупреждение участнику\n❌ — Снять предупреждение с участника\n — Посмотреть предупреждения пользователя\n\n**2-ая строка кнопок:**\n\n✅ — Выдать роль рейтинга участнику\n❎ — Снять роль рейтинга участнику\n — Список участников с ролью рейтинга\n — История нарушений`);
        
        await interaction.deferReply();
        await interaction.followUp({ 
          embeds: [embed], components: [row, row1], ephemeral: false });

          collector.on('collect', async i => {
            switch (i.customId) {
              case 'mute':
                await muteButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'unmute':
                await unMuteButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'warn':
                await warnButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'unwarn':
                await unWarnButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'listraiting':
                await listRaitingButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'infraction':
                await infractionButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'raiting':
                await raitingButton.execute(i);
                break;
              case 'unraiting':
                await unraitingButton.execute(i);
                break;
            }
          });
      
          collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collector для реакций завершен. Собрано ${collected.size} элементов.`);
          });
        },
      };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a local `hasRun` variable, included in the filter function.

```js
async function createCollector(interaction, customId, executeFunction) {

  let hasRun = false;

  const filter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.isButton() && i.customId === customId && !hasRun;

  const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });

  collector.on('collect', async i => {
    hasRun = true;
    executeFunction(i);
  });

  collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collector для кнопки ${customId} завершен. Собрано ${collected.size} элементов.`);
  });
}
```